# How an I fake a container to appear centered AND make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, containers

I am a relatively new front-end developer and never had to think outside of the box.  For work, I have a design that I haven't worked on before.

Instead of a horizontal navigation menu, we are using a vertical navigation menu that will stick to the left of the screen and we need to have a centered container.  The site needs to be responsive.

Background info:

The left aligned vertical menu is 211px in width and 300px in height.  The container is 960px wide.

Problem:

Because the navigation menu takes up 211px of the screen width, the container when centered using margin: 0 auto overlaps with the menu.  So I decided to try to fake it using the following:

```
margin: -22px 0px 0px 255px;
```

But as you can see, doing that won't guarantee that the container will appear in the same place across all browsers/platforms and it's sort of bad for responsive design.

Question:

Using the above-mentioned info, how can I properly create a vertical menu that is aligned to the left whose width is 211px and height is 300px and a 960px wide container that needs to be centered not from the screen size but rather from the menu itself? Please also keep in mind that I will need to make this responsive.

I am new to this and a bit lost.

Comment: Can you past a graphic of the layout you are wanting? I'm having a hard time picturing this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your looking to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/yvg2f/1/

If you create and extra container for the content to reside in,

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav">nav</div>
    <div id="contentContainer">
        <div id="content">content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can simply give the #content a:

```
margin: 0 auto
```

and it should stay centered. The big thing you're going to need to do is think about all these numbers a percentages. Otherwise you'll need to use some javascript to resize the #contentContainer to a size :

```
document.width-211;
```

which I wouldn't consider ideal.